# Setting the final element of a char* to NULL

Tags: c, parsing, c-strings

I have the following code. The goal is to parse a read line into tokens, but with the added capability of handling single quotes.

```
char *line = readline(prompt);
char *token;
while (*line)
{
  if (*line == '\'')
  {
    *line++;
    while (*line != '\'')
      *token++ = *line++;
    *token = NULL;
    printf("token is %s", token);
  }
  else if (*line == '\n' || *line == '\t' || *line == ' ')
  {
    while (*line != '\n' && *line != '\t' && *line != ' ')
      *token++ = *line++
    *token = NULL;
    printf("token is %s", token);
  }
}
```

I'm receiving the following error message:
"error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int’ and ‘char *’)
       *token = NULL;"

I'm not entirely sure why the compiler would complain about the assignment of '\0' to the end of my token, but remain silent for the *token++ = *line++ assignment.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Missing a semicolon...

Comment: Use `'\0'` instead of the NULL macro.

Comment: `*token` has the type `char`, `NULL` is usually a macro that expands to `(void*) 0` which has type `void*` and both types are incompatible, that's why the compiler is showing you an error message.

Answer (score 2):

Null-terminated C string is terminated with [*null character*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), which is not the same as [*null pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer).

Macro `NULL` represents a null pointer. There is no built-in macro to represent null character, so you should use character literal `'\0'`:

```
*token = '\0';
```

> With that correction, the program is throwing a segmentation fault, is there anything noticeably flawed with the logic of my approach?

Yes, `token` pointer is not initialized. Allocate memory for it on initializing

```
char *token = malloc(strlen(line)+1);
```

and then free that memory after the end of your `while` loop:

```
free(token);
```

Comment: Ah, I uploaded the wrong code, that was my original attempt, and it threw the same error. The error for this is: "cssh.c:52:7: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int’ and ‘char *’)
       *token = '\0';"

Comment: @japaneseHarryStyles Was it also missing the semicolon on the line before?

Comment: @japaneseHarryStyles That's odd, it should not give you an error. I assume that you've fixed the missing semicolon error, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's exactly the problem. I looked for that when I saw that the compiler was interpreting my dereference as a binary operator, but I guess I checked the wrong line I suppose. With that correction, the program is throwing a segmentation fault, is there anything noticeably flawed with the logic of my approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
NULL  = (void *)0  //used with pointers to mean it points to nothing or the base address
```

while

```
'\0' is an ascii NUL   //used as a string terminator which is a zeroed byte
```

so you should terminate it like

```
*token = 0;
```

or

```
*token ='\0';
```